# $L^p$ norm of boundary values of holomorphic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for an estimate of the following form:

Suppose that $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a simply connected domain. Suppose that $F$ is holomorphic and bounded on $D$ and can be holomorphically extended to the boundary $\bar D$.

Then for $1\le p \le \infty$ I am looking for a constant $C>0$ with

$$
\|F\|_{L^p(D)}\le C\|F\|_{L^p(\partial D)}.
$$

Such an inequality is true for sure but I would like to know what is the best constant $C$, if $D$ is a `nice' domain (it could depend on the ratio between the area of $D$ and the length of $\partial D$ but I am not sure)?

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This inequality holds for the unit disk with $C=1$. In all other cases of "nice" boundary it will hold only with a constant depending on the domain. To see how this constant depends on the properties of the domain, consider a conformal map
$\phi$ of your domain onto the disk, transplant your functions to the disk via this conformal map, and obtain an inequality where $|\phi'|$ will enter. Then, depending on your assumptions about the domain, obtain an estimate of $|\phi'|$,
and this will give you the constant for your domain.

Comment: More precisely, it holds with $C=1$ in the case of the unit disk provided we normalize area measure and arclength so that the area of the disk and the length of the unit circle are both one.

Comment: thank you for your answer! yes, this is also what I had... I was hoping that there exists a citeable result which makes the constant explicit in terms of geometric properties of the domain...